# How to manage Django form validation with dynamically generated forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Let's say I have the following html page:

[LIVE CODE](https://jsfiddle.net/gerasg/3dqup7ga/)

Let's say that in each row there is a form (I have to implement it), How can I do so that when I click on 'save' button (also to be implemented) all the inputs of each row are sent in the request.POST and I can process them individually in the backend.

This is my view for a new expense:

```
def new_expense(request):
    data = {
        'title': "New Expense",
    }

    data['projects'] = Project.objects.filter(is_visible=True).values('id')
    data['expense_category'] = dict((y, x) for x, y in EXPENSE_CATEGORY)
    data['expense_type'] = dict((y, x) for x, y in EXPENSE_TYPE)

    form = ExpenseForm()

    if request.method == "POST":
        reset = request.POST['reset']
        form = ExpenseForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        if reset == 'true':
            form = ExpenseForm()
    data['form'] = form
    return render(request, "expense/new_expense.html", data)
```

I would like to create a similar view for multiple `new expense` creation.

Answer (score 0):

One approach to this problem can be handling each row individually. You can use a very simple and effective tool called django_htmx for this task. Here is a nice article about how to handle formsets (like) rows: [Build dynamic forms with Htmx](https://justdjango.com/blog/dynamic-forms-in-django-htmx). Your case seems to be a very good candidate for the example in this article.

Comment: Sounds very promising, however I can't add external libraries nor install new packages to the project :(

Comment: Can people add more rows in the frontend? Like clicking an "add row" button? If not, how about using formsets? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: Yes they will be able to add new rows

Comment: Then you will have to write javascript for that. I would suggest rendering 1 row in a `<template>` tag and then in javascript get the template, clone node, alter all the id's and for attributes of the labels (you can count rows and append row number) so that for row number 5 you will get id="example-5" and for attribute in label will be for="example-5" etc... Then insert that row in the form. Store the row count in an input to send it to backedn. In the backend get the row count and loop in range row count to get each rows data.